# Grouping lines in bash up to a maximum number of lines

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

The problem is as follows:

I have a command that outputs data in lines with random timings

```
./cmd1
t0: a
t1: b
t2: c
t3: d
t4: e
t5: f
...
```

and I want to process those lines with a second command `cmd2`.

Right now, I'm using gnu parallel.

`./cmd1 | parallel cmd2`

which will call `cmd2` once per line.

I'd like, however, to batch the output generated by `cmd1` in such way that:

- Up to N lines are sent to `cmd2`
- Grouping will timeout after T seconds and `cmd2` will be called with `0 < n < N` lines.

E.g. with T=1 and N=2

`cmd1` output:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 0.1 | b |
| 0.2 | c |
| 1.3 | d |
| 1.4 | e |

will spawn jobs:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0.1 | cmd2 a b # called because there were 2 lines |
| 1.1 | cmd2 c # called because grouping timed out |
| 1.4 | cmd2 d e |

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do in `tcl` thanks to its event loop. Set up one callback for when standard input can be read to handle a line, and a periodic one that gets called every T seconds to flush the buffered lines if needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

if {[llength $argv] != 3} {
    puts stderr "Usage: $argv0 linecount timeout command"
    exit 1
}
lassign $argv nlines timeout cmd
set timeout [expr {$timeout * 1000}]

set buffer {}
proc flush_buffer {} {
    # Invoke the command with the buffered lines (if any) as arguments
    global buffer cmd
    if {[llength $buffer]} {
        exec $cmd {*}$buffer &
        set buffer {}
    }
}

proc handle_timeout {} {
    # On timeout, flush any buffered lines and requeue.
    global timeout
    flush_buffer
    after $timeout handle_timeout
}

proc read_line {fd} {
    # Read a line from a channel, buffer it, and flush buffer if full.
    global buffer nlines
    if {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
        lappend buffer $line
        if {[llength $buffer] >= $nlines} {
            flush_buffer
        }
    } elseif {[chan eof $fd]} {
        # Nothing left to read
        global forever
        flush_buffer
        set forever 1
    }
}

# Set up event handlers
after $timeout handle_timeout
chan configure stdin -blocking 0
chan event stdin readable {read_line stdin}

# And run
vwait forever
```

Example, with a couple of shell scripts to spew lines at intervals, and another to just echo its command line arguments:

```
$ ./spew.sh | ./grouper 2 1 ./printer.sh
Starting printer process
(6565) line 1
(6565) line 2
Starting printer process
(6566) line 3
Starting printer process
(6568) line 4
(6568) line 5
Starting printer process
(6569) line 6
(6569) line 7
```